# nginx tries to find index.html in a directory according to the uri

Tags: reactjs, nginx, react-router

I have this simple configuration for nginx to serve my React app:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    root /usr/share/nginx/html;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
    }
}
```

I have routes `/` and `login`. Everything works fine when I go from `localhost/` to `localhost/login` via React-Router. But when I type `localhost/login` in the browser, I get the 404 error.

To be exact, for `localhost/login` I get `"/usr/share/nginx/html/login" failed (2: No such file or directory)` in nginx console.
And for `localhost/login/` I get `"/usr/share/nginx/html/login/index.html" is not found (2: No such file or directory)`

I can't understand why nginx keep looking for `index.html` in `/usr/share/nginx/html/login/` instead of `/usr/share/nginx/html/`. Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: By path `/usr/share/nginx/html` there is an index.html?

Comment: Yes, there is `index.html` in that directory

Comment: Do you want to your app by route `/login` open `index.html`?

Comment: Yes, exactly, `index,html` on any route

Comment: I've updated my answer try to change your rules try_files like in my answer

Answer (score 3):

OK, my bad, looks like I just messed up with the config file.
In my Dockerfile I did the following

```
COPY nginx/default.conf /etc/nginx/conf.default
```

while, obviously, nginx doesn't look for config in `conf.default` file.

So I created the `nginx.conf` file:

```
events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}

http {
    server {
        listen 80;
        root /usr/share/nginx/html;

        location / {
            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
        }
    }
}
```

and wrote in the `Dockerfile`:

```
COPY nginx/nginx.conf /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
```

That solved the problem. Thanks for help!

Answer (score 2):

You don't need `location`

Try to change code in config like there

```
server {
    listen 80;
    root /usr/share/nginx/html;
    index index.html;
    location / {
      try_files /index.html =404;
  }
}
```

If you have another static files also add this code, (after `location / {}` block)

```
location /files/ { 
  autoindex on;
  root /var/www/[your repo name]/files;
}
```

Comment: Still the same behavior